# Replace Icelandic months names with English months names using an array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, date, datetime

I have some date variables that contain Icelandic months name like:

```
$date = '27. júní 2018 04:53';
```

I want to replace these months names with English months names:

```
$icelandic = array('Janúar', 'Febrúar', 'Mars', 'Apríl', 'Maí', 'Júní', 'Júlí', 'Ágúst', 'September', 'Oktober', 'Nóvember', 'Desember');
```

Or an associative array:

```
 $icelandic = array('Janúar' => '', 'Febrúar' => '', 'Mars' => '', 'Apríl' => '', 'Maí' => '', 'Júní' => '', 'Júlí' => '', 'Ágúst' => '', 'September' => '', 'Oktober' => '', 'Nóvember' => '', 'Desember' => '');
```

As you see or know that the months names aren't the whole word, But maybe only 3 or 4 characters from the word.

So if a part of these values in the array exists in the date variable, Then it's replaced with the English month.

The replaced English months could be the whole world, As `new DateTime()` handles that.

So the above variable could be :

```
$date = '27. june 2018 04:53';
```

Or :

```
$date = '27. jun 2018 04:53';
```

UPDATE:

What I have tried:

```
$icelandic = array('Janúar', 'Febrúar', 'Mars', 'Apríl', 'Maí', 'Júní', 'Júlí', 'Ágúst', 'September', 'Oktober', 'Nóvember', 'Desember');

$english = array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');

for($i=0; $i < count($icelandic); $i++) {
    $date = str_replace($icelandic[$i], $english[$i], $date);
}
```

Or a check first using `strpos()`:

```
if(strpos($icelandic[$i], $date)){
    $date = str_replace($icelandic[$i], $english[$i], $date);
}
```

I don't know the short form of both English and Icelandic months in date form.

Comment: I would like to see what you have tried so far....

Comment: do you know every version of every month name you need to replace?

Comment: @mickmackusa, I know it's not a free coding service, I provided some information in my question about the ideas I have.
Maybe I could do something, But it may not me the best way and take much code and execution time.
This would be executed on a real website.

Comment: @mickmackusa, Also you have the right to delete your answer, I didn't see it, But thanks anyway.

Comment: I shared the ways I think it could be done with, using arrays, Two arrays or one array, The key is the English and the value is the Icelandic.

But what if what I tried is far different from your answer?

Comment: @mickmackusa, Question is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QZntM))

```
$icelandic = array(
    'jan' => 'January',
    'feb' => 'February',
    'mar' => 'March',
    'apr' => 'April',
    'maí' => 'May',
    'jún' => 'June',
    'júl' => 'July',
    'ágú' => 'August',
    'okt' => 'October',
    'sep' => 'September',
    'nóv' => 'November',
    'des' => 'December',
);

$tests = array(
    '1. júní 2018 04:53',
    '2. Ágú 2018 04:53',
    '3. Maí 2018 04:53',
    '4. nóvember 2018 04:53',
    '5. Des 2018 04:53'
);

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    echo "\n$test -> ";
    echo preg_replace_callback('~(' . implode('|', array_keys($icelandic)) . ')\pL*~iu', function($m)use($icelandic) {
            return  $icelandic[mb_strtolower($m[1], 'UTF-8')];
         }, $test);
}
```

Output:

```
1. júní 2018 04:53 -> 1. June 2018 04:53
2. Ágú 2018 04:53 -> 2. August 2018 04:53
3. Maí 2018 04:53 -> 3. May 2018 04:53
4. nóvember 2018 04:53 -> 4. November 2018 04:53
5. Des 2018 04:53 -> 5. December 2018 04:53
```

Here is the logic:

Your lookup array must have:

1. keys which contain the first three icelandic letters (with accents) in lowercase
2. values which contain your desired English month name (I am using the full month name)

`preg_replace_callback()` will used because functional processes will be applied to each match.

The pattern consists of all of the lookup keys, bound together with `|` (to represent OR logic).  These first three characters are stored in Capture Group #1.  The optional trailing letters are matched by `\pL*` which is the unicode-safe version of "any letter".  The `i` pattern modifier allows case-insensitive matching.  The `u` modifier allows unicode character matching.

The first capture group (`$m[1]`) will converted to (multibyte-safe) lowercase and then used to access the desired value from the lookup array which will replace the "fullstring" match (`$m[0]`) so that none of the original Icelandic word will remain.

Comment: Thanks, I see some functions for the first time :D, But I have a question: 'Could the $test be a variable not an array?'

Comment: Yes, definitely.  This is simply how I displayed the versatility of the solution.